# Optimization of cost function using newton method

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, approximation, newtons-method

I am studying "Distributed newton method for deep neural network", a research paper by CC Wang and his associates.

In the section of "Non-hessian Newton method", there is a mention of second-order approximation of the cost function f(θ).

It is not clear why the hessian being positive definite , solving the second order approximation is same as solving the linear system.   [Image of the linear system equation and the statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q89SQ.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Ask at stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Kindly close this, I 've posted the same question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375147/optimization-of-cost-function-using-newton-method . Thank you for letting me know